# Como tratar una lista de información traida de AJAX en un objeto JSON mediante Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, lista, jsonobject

Estoy trayendo desde un servlet mediante un metodo AJAX, una lista de objetos, los cuales transformo previamente en un objeto JSON antes de traerlos de vuelta. El resultado que muestra la consola de JAVA del objeto JSON antes del envío es el siguiente:

```
List<PreguntaRespuestasMaternidad> listaMaternidad = new ArrayList<>();
listaMaternidad = new RespuestaspreguntasDAOImpl().extraerBloqueMaternidad();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(listaMaternidad);
System.out.println(json);
```

```
[{"idpregunta":127,"descripcion":"Si-No","tipo":2,"nivel":0,"orden":3,"cajaAdicional":false,"minSlider":0,"maxSlider":0,"bloque":0,"idRespuesta":92},{"idpregunta":128,"descripcion":"Si-No","tipo":2,"nivel":0,"orden":4,"cajaAdicional":true,"minSlider":0,"maxSlider":0,"bloque":0,"idRespuesta":93},{"idpregunta":129,"descripcion":"Pues si-Adios-Con fallos","tipo":3,"nivel":0,"orden":5,"cajaAdicional":true,"minSlider":0,"maxSlider":0,"bloque":0,"idRespuesta":94}]
```

En la consola de Google Chrome interrogo como lo trae
[image: consola Google Chrome]

No conozco mucho de Javascript no es mi lenguaje principal, entiendo que si viene como muestra la foto, lo esta reconociendo como un array. He intentado recorrerlo con distintos bucles con el fin de comprobar que podría recoger cada objeto por separado y tratar su información pero no he tenido éxito. El único que me ha devuelto algo de información fue el bucle forEach y solo me mostró por consola los valores numéricos del principio [0,1,2].

¿Tengo que transformar la información que trae el objeto JSON previamente antes de trabajar con los objetos que trae? ¿O hay alguna manera de trabajar con ellos directamente como he intentado con los bucles?

Edit: Con esta información quiero pintar unos elementos HTML mediante Javascript, en este caso sería unas preguntas dentro de un formulario que estoy generando, de ahí que intente leer mediante un bucle la información del JSON en javascript, sin ningun resultado.

Un saludo

**Edit 2: Solucionado, el fallo fue que la variable json que se llama igual "json" y que es la que trae la información del servlet, la tenia escrita en mayusculas dentro de los bucles que generé para recorrer dicha información (debído a un intento de crear un objeto en javascript dentro de las múltiples opciones que estuve provando con anterioridad para dar solución al problema). La variable del cast era "JSON" y esto provoco el fallo de todo.**

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes ya es suficiente, pero no nos basta con esa info, puedes agregar el objeto `JSON` completo ? también que quieres al final con esos datos, pintarlos en el documento `HTML` ? tomar decisiones en base a estos ?

Comment: deberías especificar que quieres hacer con los datos.

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo ya he añadido el contenido que pides al post.

Comment: @IsmaelGarciaMartin lo que quieres es muy abierto, es algo básicamente basado en experiencia ya que iterar el objeto es una cosa pero crear el formulario es otra. Nota: La iteraccion la logras facil con un `foreach` `data.forEach(element => {
    element.idpregunta
});`

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo, el tema es que iterarlo no me deja, me da error en la mayoría de los bucles, por ejemplo, el que me has mencionado me provoca un error:


ServletCreaFormulario:252 Uncaught TypeError: JSON.forEach is not a function

Comment: @IsmaelGarciaMartin te lo pase porque lo he probado en javascript con el mismo objeto que publicaste en la pregunta.

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo ¿Puede ser que esté teniendo algún problema con las versiones? en el listado del error me sale como ultimo nivel de error la libreria jquery, estoy revisando y en el proyecto estoy usando jQuery v3.3.1

Comment: @IsmaelGarciaMartin coloca el código de la petición AJAX

Comment: @AlbertHidalgo vale he encontrado el fallo por el cual no me iteraba el objeto json de AJAX, resulta que lo tenia escrito la variable en mayúsculas debido a una prueba anterior en la que hacia un cast de javascript para intentar generar un objeto y dicha variable era en mayúsculas. Ahora los bucles me funcionan, incluido el que tu me mencionaste arriba. 

No me puedo creer que fuera un fallo tan tonto. Gracias por la ayuda. Creo que ahora podre proseguir con la agregación de elementos HTML a mi formulario.